# Insert a Variable into the Name of Another Variable

Tags: python, string, user-interface, variables, pyqt5

sorry that this question will be poorly worded as I do not even know the term used to Google it to even get a real valid question formed.

In short I have a lot of UI elements with the same naming convention and instead of listing hundreds of lines of code, I want to make a simply for loop (range of a list) to populate the information.

My example

```
var = "name"

{var}_label.text("Name?")
{var}_textEdit.setText("")
```

I would like something like that and it would know that it would be (in this example) name_label.text and name_textEdit. Is there a way to do this?

A real example (not full working code, but you can see the issue):

```
if self.date_edit.text() == "":
QMessageBox.warning(self, "Warning", f"You need to fill out an date header.")
return
```

In this example the "date" should be able to be populated in both the UI variable name and the message box text.

Code that I have tried:

```
my_list = ["date_edit", "date_label"]

for item in range(len(my_list)):
    print(item)
    self.my_list[item].setText("hey")
```

Error: AttributeError: 'Ui' object has no attribute 'my_list'

however there is a self.date_edit

Final example of **working** code:

```
my_list = ["date"]

for item in range(len(my_list)):
    d = self.__dict__
    label = d.get(f'{my_list[item]}_label')
    text_edit = d.get(f'{my_list[item]}_edit')
    if label:
        label.setText("Name?")
    if text_edit:
        text_edit.setText("WOW")
```

Thank you everyone for your help :).

Comment: Why not just stick them in a list or dictionary?

Comment: Can you give me example of how you would implement that?  I know how to loop through lists, but I am not sure how I would insert the variable names into the UI element names as it is a name of a variable. I am trying to nest variables to create variable names, that is the part I am stuck on.

Comment: `elements = {"name": (the_label, the_textEdit)}`. Then `elements["name"]` to get the label/edit pair. I have it as a tuple of elements. It could also be a list, or some other structure depending on the circumstances.

Comment: So how do I insert that into another variable name? For example it would be self.name[0].setText()?

Comment: @ScottUlmer you **really** should not be using dynamic variables like this. There are ways, but again, almost certainly, there is a better way to accmoplish whatever it is you are trying to accomplish, likely by just using a *container* like a `list` or a `dict`

Comment: @ScottUlmer `elements["name"][0].setText()`. The inner tuples could be `NamedTuple`s too, then you can refer to each by a name instead of `[0]` and `[1]`. And to add another entry: `elements.put("new name", (new_label, new_edit))`.

Comment: Sorry, I must be very dense... I can't figure out how to get it to work. I have:                 list = ["date", "memo"]

        for item in range(len(list)):
            print(item)
            self.list[item]_edit.setText("hey")
This is invalid syntax.

Comment: @ScottUlmer Why do you have `_edit` in there?

Comment: because I have a self.date_label (that says "Date") and is a label and a self.date_edit which is a textEdit in PyQt5 (for user input)

Comment: @ScottUlmer "date_edit" would be, with the code I presented in my comments above, `elements["date"][1]`. Or again, you could use a named tuple instead of a normal tuple if you want to refer to the second field as `edit` instead of `[1]`.

Comment: Sorry I keep bugging you, I am getting an error still: AttributeError: 'Ui' object has no attribute 'my_list'... <p>code is:         my_list = ["date_edit", "date_label"]

        for item in range(len(my_list)):
            print(item)
            self.my_list[item].setText("hey")<p>Can you add a quick full example of your code? just a list of two items and have it work?

Comment: @ScottUlmer That error is becuase you have `self.my_list`, but `my_list` isn't a member of the object judging my your definition of it. And when I get home I'll try to write up a gist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can get them from the object's dictionary of variables and assign them to new variable names?

```
var = 'test'

d = self.__dict__
label = d.get(f'{var}_label')
text_edit = d.get(f'{var}_textEdit')
if label:
    label.text("Name?")
if text_edit:
    text_edit.setText("")
```

Comment: I tried that and I was getting "None" , I tried to change it a little and I got "AttributeError: 'Ui' object has no attribute 'label'"

Comment: `if label:` is meant to guard against the possibility that the variable is not in `locals`.  Perhaps it is in your `globals`? Are you sure that the object exists?

Comment: So I did a simple print("here") inside the if label, and it never printed. I think the issue is that it is inside a class. The correct name for the label is self.date_label, and the correct code would be self.date_label.setText("")

Comment: Then instead of `local()`, use `self.__dict__`.

Comment: You are a genius, thank you SO much :D.